# uninitialize constant user (work with dto)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm learning rails using Devise for authentication purpose and make a User by `Rails  generate Devise user` it creates a user model for me & every thing is works fine But when i put my file (user.rb) to User component
[image: Component]

where I have user_dto & user_service file as well.

problem occur when I try to create a migration by `rails g migration add_authentication_token_to_users "authentication_token:string{30}:uniq"` and i got an error here **uninitialized constant User (NameError)
**
error is resolved when i put back user.rb file to models but i have to work in this way , is their any solution to generate a migration  with putting this user.rb file  to component not in model.

Comment: Why do you need to move the file from models to components directory?

Comment: Add `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("components", "users", "{*/}")]` in `application.rb` and then execute `rake db:migrate`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, rails paradigm is "convention over configuration", and maybe you should learn and stick to the convention instead of changing everything up to a convention from another framework/style because this will most likely lead to more problems in the future.

Comment: yes you guyz may be right  but the company im working in,  already work in this way from a long time and have already running projects that's why I'm restrict to work in this way, at the end they told me to don't change your user.rb model in case when you are using devise this is the exceptional case .